# Pass user/pass to curl from a local file

Tags: authentication, curl, curl-commandline

I know that you can give cURL a user/pass combination using the -u flag which is great.  What I'm trying to do is get the credentials from a file on the filesystem and pass that in.  For example

**in auth.conf**

```
id=q8374grf748
key=47w34kurgfuegurfgser7348gfeurfgyu
```

then I'd like to do the equivalent:

```
curl -u id:key http://example.com
```

Comment: Ok so you already have a plan. The next step would be to execute the plan. Good luck with that!

Comment: @Spanky its a very good question. I don't know why people flagged your question to close it down. You have asked a valid question from the perspective of `curl-commandline`. I am also interested to know the answer of this question.

Answer (score 1):

You can Try this out :-

```
curl --user user:pass https://whatever.com/login
```

Even if you need to save cookie and try to access another page in site try this

first

```
curl --user user:pass --cookie-jar ./cookiefile https://whatever.com/login
```

Second

```
curl --cookie ./cookiefile https://whatever.com/secondpage
```